# Why would a PHP cURL request work on localhost but not on server (getting 403 forbidden)?

Tags: php, asp.net, curl, web-scraping

I am trying to submit a form using PHP cURL. Everything works great on localhost but not when I upload it to a server (SiteGround). My code makes an initial get request to get the hidden data needed to make a submission to an asp.net form. Currently, I can't even get the initial page to load that has the form data on it. I receive a 403 Forbidden code in the header (this is new). Previously I was able to submit the form before getting the website's 403 page that loaded the message *"If you are experiencing difficulty..."*, which is where the result would have been loaded. So why would I be able to access the information on localhost but not when I load it on to a server?

```
$registration = 18217198;

// Make initial cURL to get hidden data in form before making a post request
$url = 'https://www.angus.org/Animal/EpdPedSearch.aspx';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36'],
));
$html = curl_exec($curl);

if (curl_error($curl)) {
    echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($curl);
}

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

// Traverse to get required data for form submission.
$viewState = $doc->getElementById('__VIEWSTATE')->getAttribute('value');
$hidAniKey = $doc->getElementById('_TSM_HiddenField_')->getAttribute('value');
$eventValidation = $doc->getElementById('__EVENTVALIDATION')->getAttribute('value');
$viewStateGen = $doc->getElementById('__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR')->getAttribute('value');

$postFields = array(
    '__VIEWSTATE' => $viewState,
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR' => $viewStateGen,
    '__EVENTVALIDATION' => $eventValidation,
    'ctl00$MainContent$HidSchDataid' => $hidAniKey,
    'ctl00$cphBodyLeft1$ucEpdPedSearch$uctxtIdentNum' => $registration,
    '__SCROLLPOSITIONX' => 0,
    '__SCROLLPOSITIONY' => 0,
    'ctl00$ucddlSearchType' => 'Animal',
    'ctl00$ucStatesList' => 'noState',
    'ctl00$cphBodyLeft1$ucEpdPedSearch$ucCmbNameSearchOptions' => 0,
    'ctl00$cphBodyLeft1$ucEpdPedSearch$ucbtnSearch' => 'Search'
);

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36'],
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postFields,
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);

if (curl_error($curl)) {
    echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($curl);
}
curl_close($curl);

print_r( $response );
```

Comment: What's in your server's logs?

Comment: your server's IP is probably banned. (maybe an entire IP range is banned) maybe use a proxy?